# Keycloak with google offline refresh tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, keycloak

How can keycloak be configured to authenticate with google with `access_type=offline`? For this reason I cannot get a refresh token.

It [looks](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/213) like google doesn't implement the `scope=offline_access` as it should be.

Comment: Have you tried visiting [this github post](https://github.com/metadatacenter/cedar-docs/wiki/Configuring-Keycloak-to-use-Google-Identity-Provider)?

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to the offline word in that entire repository.